# DuckDB: How to check with a WHERE if a VARCHAR is in a LIST

Tags: sql, duckdb

I have the following LIST called dois:

```
["10.3390/polym11050769", "10.1016/j.ijbiomac.2022.09.237"]
```

And this VARCHAR called article_doi: "10.3390/polym11050769"

I would like to write a `WHERE` condition to check if the `VARCHAR` is contained in the list:

```
WHERE CAST(article_doi AS VARCHAR) IN (dois)
```

But I am getting the following error:

> duckdb error: Conversion Error: Type VARCHAR with value '10.1016/j.jeurceramsoc.2004.01.003' can't be cast to the destination type LIST

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved using the following WHERE condition:

```
WHERE list_contains(dois, CAST(article_doi AS VARCHAR))
```

Comment: Indeed `list_contains` is a good way to solve this.